# Unable to resolve signature for call of date

Tags: html, angular

```
            <td>
                {{ fundInfo.beginDate | date: "yyyy-MM-dd" }}
            </td>
```

this error occurs in src\app\primeng-test-b\primeng-test-b.component.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Make sure that your **fundInfo.beginDate** is of type **Date**.
This should work fine.

Comment: it is of type Date. I restart the visual studio code and restart the application.The error is missing.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this error by restarting my vscode.

Comment: is correct!  This should be the accepted answer.
I was having errors appearing everywhere in my custom libs in Angular10 project.  EG. I had async and json pipes giving this same error.  I also solved this error by restarting my vscode.  Errors have gone.